# Android serialization issue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write object data to a file (how it's done in a standard java program) in an android program and am running in to some issues. Here's the code:

```
public static final String storeDir = "Adata"; 
public static final String storeFile = "albums";


public static void write(ArrayList<Album> albums) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(storeDir + File.separator + storeFile));
    oos.writeObject(albums);
}

public static ArrayList<Album> read() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream(storeDir + File.separator + storeFile));

    return (ArrayList<Album>)ois.readObject();
}
```

At startup the app crashes and says, "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Adata/albums (No such file or directory)

The folder Adata folder is in the project folder at the same point as the src. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add this line and check the result? System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

Comment: Have you gone through this? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html  "The folder Adata folder is in the project folder at the same point as the src."  Your project folder structure will not be duplicated in the filesystem of the android device.

Comment: @VascoLameiras Why System.out?  What's wrong with the debugger, that's what it's for!

Comment: @Simon True, the debugger is always preferred.

Comment: it was probably easier to type than `Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "" + System.getProperty("user.dir"));` but eh

Comment: 'Log' is not the debugger!  Log is for, er, logging, not debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want in to store in the external directory

Replace your storedir and storeFile as

```
public static final String storeDir = = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public static final String storeFile = "Adata/albums";
```

Also you may need to provide permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

To get a better understanding, take a look at [Developer site.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)